# Ruby - AD/LDAP auth - read user details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-directory, ldap

I am trying LDAP/Active directory authentication. This code is working perfectly, I can authenticate. 
My question is - How do I retrieve user information from AD? I want to read firstname, lastname, fullname, email etc from AD for the authenticated user.

Answer (score 1):

In LDAP, users do not authenticate, connections are authenticated. Once the authorization state
of the connection has been established (by a successful bind request), code that desires to
retrieve information from the directory must transmit a search request to the directory server
and then interpret the response.

Search requests must contain a minimum the following parameters:

- the base object at which the search starts (no objects above the base objects are returned)
- the scope of the search: `base` is the base object itself, `one` is the base object and
  one level below thw base object, `sub` is the base object and all entries below the base object.
- a filter which limits the entries returned to those entries which match the assertion in the
  filter

A list of attributes can also be supplied, though many, but not all, LDAP APIs will request all 
user attributes if none are supplied in the search request.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/mastering-ldap-search-filters/)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ldap-programming-best-practices/)